# How to get the day of the week in DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime, weekday

How to get the day of the week in DateTime ?

I can’t find the way to get the day of the week from a DateTime.
It’s can be number or string, both are ok.

```
$today = new DateTime("today");
echo $ today->//whatever to get Friday, Monday or 5, 0
```

How to get the day of the week in DateTime ?

Edit:
I am using DateTime, not date.

Comment: refer this [https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp]

Comment: You know, date and DateTime are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use format() function

```
$today->format('l') //Sunday through Saturday
$today->format('w') //0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)
```